# Preventing duplicate NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data

Consider two entities `Author` and `Book` that are in a many-to-many relationship that are imported into my CoreData store from an external database. What I am confused about is, should I create a new `NSManagedObject` for each author, even if this author is already in the store? How do I even know that two authors with the same name are the same person? I could for instance end up with 10 John Smiths, and 5 of them are the same person, but there is no way to check this when importing the data, right? Suppose I want to do a fetchrequest for one of these John Smiths, I will still get 10 results. He may also appear as J. Smith, or J.A. Smith. But J. Smith could also be Jenny Smith.

Should I just create an `NSManagedObject` for each author, and not worry about possible duplicates, or are there other ways around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I even know that two authors with the same name are the same person?

You don't, and that's the core of your problem right there. You need to allow duplicate names, because names are (usually) not unique. Any technical solution to avoiding or removing duplicates based on name is virtually guaranteed to corrupt your data.

It's not clear where your data is coming from, so it's hard to say what the best fix is. If this is user-entered data, let the user edit an existing author to add or remove titles, to prevent a duplicate. Offer the option to merge two entries in case the user accidentally creates a duplicate.

If the data comes from an online service of some kind, you pretty much have to take what they give you. If they have duplicate entries for authors, you can't reliably do anything about it. You could easily find duplicate names, but that doesn't mean they're the same person.

Comment: So would that mean that a many-to-many relationship is not required between book and author, and a one-to-many would be sufficient?

Comment: No, because some books have multiple co-authors, and of course some people write more than one book.

Comment: That is true, but in my app case information is presented and imported 'top-down', book before author. So even though the same author can write many books, if I don't check for duplicates (my original question) every author will be unique to one book.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment may come across as snotty. What I meant to say was, in the case of my app when importing data, the way the incoming data is structured (XML), books are always first, followed by the authors, never the other way around. So even though I agree with you that some authors can be writing more than one book, unless I figure out a way to determine if John Smith from book1 is the same as John Smith from book2, I will end up with duplicate names. Which is fine with me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

use a fetch or create pattern as explained in the apple CoreData docs

Core Data doesnt have an implicit uniquing algorithm.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html

(they call it find or create) ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to disambiguate people (or authors) you would need either a "unique" attribute, say an `author_id` which is guaranteed to be unique when an author will be created.

The other approach is to use heuristics to determine if an object has possibly duplicates This second approach sounds more complex, and actually it IS more complex ;)

Unfortunately, Core Data does not support "unique attributes" (unique keys).

Both approaches can be implemented as proper managed object "validations", which get invoked when the context will be saved.

A sophisticated solution would use a *separate* index maintained per unique attribute and per context. Using Core Data queries as shown in the sample snippets "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently" in order to confirm that the "unique constraint" is fulfilled each time the context is saved, will become quite slow for large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 9, Apple introduced unique constraints to Core Data. Now you can specify an attribute that has to be unique.